# Getting latest pastebin .txt from user webBrowser c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control, pastebin

The user that I get my service updates from uses Pastebin. I need to regularly update my custom servers. Therefore, I need the most current .txt from his Pastebin. I would like to automatically get the Link for the most current one. Therefore, my service updater can read it. I use Windows Forms in visual studio c#.

Tried getting the ID from the html page, but couldn't get the lastest .txt from his pastebin.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://pastebin.com/u/xxxxx");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(latestandgreatest).InvokeMember("Click");
url = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri; 
NewestUpdateLink = url;
```

Obviously "lastestandgreatest" some how represents the link to the newest .txt file that the user has posted...

Comment: There is a `table` in the page having `id=maintable` which has a `tbody`. The second `tr` of the table is the latest post. The first `td` of the second row, has an `a` tag which its `href` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can not download the file immediately after navigating to the website. Navigate to the website in form load

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://pastebin.com/jFhS1daA");
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    }
```

In the web browser document completed action find the link you wanna download and invoke click event

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the download link by text
        HtmlElement htmlElement = (from HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A") select element)
            .Where(x => string.Compare(x.InnerText, "download", true) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
        if (htmlElement != null)
        {
            htmlElement.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
```